# what is serialization in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

what is serialization in .Net

Comment: There's only one answer for this.... Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization)

Comment: Serialization is process of converting objects into form so that it can be saved to disk or database or shared across network. For that the object type defination has to be serializable and it must define howe the instances can be serialized or deserialized.

Comment: @ck - *facepalm* ... I hate these sorts of comments, how the hell do you think 95% of the people end up at stack overflow? by GOOGLING these questions, so just answer it... the site is a Q and A site, he asked a question so get on and answer it - it is a legitmate programming question too. If you dont like it press the BACK button and go elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), which is not specific to .NET, is the process of converting an in-memory object into some form of bits and bytes that are suitable for transmission (e.g. over the internet) or storage (e.g. on disk).

The complement to serialization is deserialization which takes the serialized data and reconstitutes the original object representation.

Comment: +1 for just answering the question.... give it a few weeks and when people search google for "What is serialization" they may well end on this page.