# What is deserialize and serialize in JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization, json-serialization

I have seen the terms "deserialize" and "serialize" with JSON. What do they mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization)

Answer (score 438):

JSON is a format that encodes objects in a string. **[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) means to convert an object into that string**, and **deserialization is its inverse operation (convert string -> object)**.

When transmitting data or storing them in a file, the data are required to be byte strings, but complex objects are seldom in this format. Serialization can convert these complex objects into byte strings for such use. After the byte strings are transmitted, the receiver will have to recover the original object from the byte string. This is known as deserialization.

Say, you have an object:

```
{foo: [1, 4, 7, 10], bar: "baz"}
```

serializing into JSON will convert it into a string:

```
'{"foo":[1,4,7,10],"bar":"baz"}'
```

which can be stored or sent through wire to anywhere. The receiver can then deserialize this string to get back the original object. `{foo: [1, 4, 7, 10], bar: "baz"}`.

Comment: @kennytm - I am trying to wrap my head around sending stuff over the wire. Regardless of whether I use binary encoding or use json, xml or proto buf - the data always has to be in bytes before they can be sent over the wire. Is that true?

Comment: @Nirmal Yes. ___

Comment: A mnemonic device I use to remember the difference is that "Serialization turns objects into serial numbers"

Comment: So why don't we just ```"{foo: [1, 4, 7, 10], bar: "baz"}"```

Comment: @kennytm, I'm wandering too _so why don't we just `"{foo: [1, 4, 7, 10], bar: "baz"}"`?_. Is quoting `foo` and `bar` a typo in your answer, a convention, a necessity or what?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis JSON Properties must be in quotes. It is a necessity - check out the first example on the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: serialization is converting into stream of bytes and when we reconstruct we need some format or standard like JSON or XML. That's why we use serialization with JSON or XML. Is it right? @kennytm

Answer (score 61):

## Serialize and Deserialize

> In the context of data storage, **serialization** (or serialisation) is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer) or transmitted (for example, across a network connection link) and reconstructed later. [...]
>
> The opposite operation, extracting a data structure from a series of bytes, is **deserialization**.

– [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

## JSON

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is an open standard file format and data interchange format that uses human-readable text to store and transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and arrays (or other serializable values). It is a common data format with diverse uses in electronic data interchange, including that of web applications with servers.
>
> JSON is a language-independent data format. It was derived from JavaScript, but many modern programming languages include code to generate and parse JSON-format data. JSON filenames use the extension .json.

– [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

## Explained using Python

In Python **serialization** does nothing else than just converting the given data structure into its valid JSON pendant (e.g., Python's `True` will be converted to JSON's `true` and the dictionary itself will be converted to a string) and vice versa for **deserialization**.

### Python vs. JSON

You can easily spot the difference between Python and JSON representations in a side-by-side comparison. For example, by examining their Boolean values. Have a look at the following table for the basic types used in both contexts:

| **Python** | **JSON** |
| --- | --- |
| `True` | `true` |
| `False` | `false` |
| `None` | `null` |
| `int`, `float` | `number` |
| `str` (with single `'`, double `"` and tripple `"""` quotes) | `string` (only double `"` quotes) |
| `dict` | `object` |
| `list`, `tuple` | `array` |

### Code Example

Python builtin module `json` is the standard way to do [serialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) and [deserialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```py
import json

data = {
    'president': {
        "name": """Mr. Presidente""",
        "male": True,
        'age': 60,
        'wife': None,
        'cars': ('BMW', "Audi")
    }
}

# serialize
json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

print(json_data)
# {
#   "president": {
#     "name": "Mr. Presidente",
#     "male": true,
#     "age": 60,
#     "wife": null,
#     "cars": [
#       "BMW",
#       "Audi"
#     ]
#   }
# }

# deserialize
restored_data = json.loads(json_data) # deserialize
```

Sources: [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-json/), [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-json-dump-and-json-dumps/)

Comment: If you `print(type(json_data))`, it is a `str`. So the dict object is converted to a str.

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation of Serialize and Deserialize using Python**

In python, **pickle module** is used for serialization. So, the serialization process is called **pickling** in Python. This module **is available in Python standard library**.

**Serialization using pickle**

```
import pickle

#the object to serialize
example_dic={1:"6",2:"2",3:"f"}

#where the bytes after serializing end up at, wb stands for write byte
pickle_out=open("dict.pickle","wb")
#Time to dump
pickle.dump(example_dic,pickle_out)
#whatever you open, you must close
pickle_out.close()
```

The PICKLE file (can be opened by a text editor like notepad) contains this (serialized data):

€}q (KX   6qKX   2qKX   fqu.

**Deserialization using pickle**

```
import pickle

pickle_in=open("dict.pickle","rb")
get_deserialized_data_back=pickle.load(pickle_in)

print(get_deserialized_data_back)
```

Output:

{1: '6', 2: '2', 3: 'f'}

Comment: The user asked about JSON not pickle, though. This is somewhat offtopic.

Comment: This is original question: What is deserialize and serialize in JSON? I used Python's pickle module to demonstrate the idea. I have used a tool to explain an idea. You are focusing on the tool more than the idea.

Answer (score 3):

**What is Serialization**

Serialization is the process of converting a data object into a byte stream.

**What is a byte stream**

A byte stream is just a stream of binary data. Because only binary data can be stored or transported.

**What is byte string vs byte stream**

Sometimes you see people use the words byte string as well. String encodings of bytes are called byte strings. Then it can explain what is JSON as below.

**What’s the relationship between JSON and serialization**

JSON is a string format representational of byte data. JSON is encoded in UTF-8. So while we see human readable strings, behind the scenes strings are encoded as bytes in UTF-8.