# Run a SQL Server stored procedure directly from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE current_call
    @call_id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        dbo.Call.call_id, dbo.Call.city, dbo.Call.call_received, 
        dbo.Call.call_transfer, dbo.Call.call_response, dbo.Call.call_depart, 
        dbo.Call.call_arrive, dbo.Call.call_return, dbo.Call.call_end, 
        dbo.Priority.name AS priorityName, dbo.Call_Status.name as Call_Status, 
        dbo.Station.station_name, dbo.City.city_name, dbo.Protocol.name AS protocolName
    FROM     
        dbo.City 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Call 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Priority ON dbo.Call.priority = dbo.Priority.priority_id 
        ON dbo.City.city_id = dbo.Call.city 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Protocol ON dbo.Call.protocol_category = dbo.Protocol.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Station 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Ambulance ON dbo.Station.station_id = dbo.Ambulance.ambulance_station 
        ON dbo.Call.amb_id = dbo.Ambulance.ambulance_id
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Call_Status ON dbo.Call.call_status = dbo.Call_Status.call_status_id
    WHERE 
        dbo.Call.call_id = @call_id;
END
```

I'm trying to call it through a controller and print the retrieved fields as a `json` string with no luck!

This is my controller:

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<String> GetTwo(int c_id)
{
    using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
    {
        entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        var query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<ObjectResult>("exec [dbo].[current_call] @call_id", new SqlParameter("call_id", c_id)).ToList();

        return Json (query.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The result type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.'

I also tried the following code and the result was `"-1"`

```
var query = entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [dbo].[current_call] @call_id", new SqlParameter("call_id", c_id)).toString();
```

Comment: Well, [ObjectResult **is** abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectresult?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/archive/blogs/mazhou/use-dynamic-type-in-entity-framework-4-1-sqlquery-method) does not work with dynamic types:

> if you want to use the dynamic type or anonymous type as its [`SqlQuery`]
>   return type, you will probably get your code compiled but receive
>   exceptions during runtime.

Also note that, you can't just call `ToString()` to convert your `List<object>` to json, you need to [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json) them.

*Note: In this answer I am going to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization, however there are other [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).*

---

I recommend creating a model for your SP result, this way you can project `SqlQuery`'s result into your model... defining a model also has the benefit of using `[JsonProperty]` attribute, which is helpful for mapping your properties to a different name when serializing them to json.

```
public class CurrentCall
{
    // [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Caller_Id")] <-- json property name (if different)
    public long call_id { get; set }
    public string city { get; set }
    public DateTime call_received { get; set }
    public string call_transfer { get; set }
    public string call_response { get; set }
    public DateTime call_depart { get; set }
    public DateTime call_arrive { get; set }
    public DateTime call_return { get; set }
    public DateTime call_end { get; set }
    public string priorityName { get; set }
    public bool Call_Status { get; set }
    public string station_name { get; set }
    public string city_name { get; set }
    public string protocolName { get; set }
}
```

Then you can get the result:

```
var currentCalls = entities.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentCall>("exec [dbo].[current_call] @call_id", new SqlParameter("call_id", c_id)).ToList();
```

If you want to return the result as serialized json, then try:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentCalls); 
return Json(jsonResult)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working with a minor edit on the call of the `stored-procedure`. I edited your response. `entities.Database.SqlQuery<List<CurrentCall>>` is not needed. Instead, I'm using `entities.Database.SqlQuery<CurrentCall>`.