# JSON deserialize with newtonsoft

Tags: json

I have recently worked with JSON and I don't understand how to deserialize a string like this:

```
{"brands":{"AC Cobra":{"acr":"ACC","name":"AC Cobra"},"AMG":{"acr":"AMG","name":"AMG"}},"message":null,"token":"bca5af89f5f46eddeb6c17fds2bc57a50d6a62881b8"}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3316779/7841468

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is deserialize and serialize in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json)