# How to generate Joi validations via code, based on an object and save it in a file using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to generate Joi validations via code based on an object. I would like to know if there is a way to generate them programatically and store them into a file. I tried the following way:

Lets say I have an object as follows:

```
let obj = [{
  Key: 'key1',
  Type: 'string'  
}]
```

A function to generate an object of Joi validations:

```
function getJoiObject(data) {
    const obj = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (data[key].Type === "string")
            obj[data[key].Key] = Joi.string();
        else if (data[key].Type === "integer")
            obj[data[key].Key] = Joi.number();
        else if (data[key].Type === "boolean")
            obj[data[key].Key] = Joi.boolean();
    });
    return obj;
}
```

I saved the object onto a file and used it in another file for validations.

```
 fs.writeFileSync('validations.json', JSON.stringify({res:getJoiObject(obj)}));
```

The problem is that when I import the validations.json into another file and validate it with data, it wouldn't work.

```
const a = {key1:'abc'};
Joi.object(validations.res).validate(a)
```

Could you please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Joi` has methods to serialize and deserialize its schemas, but they aren't fully documented (as of v17.6). I had a similar question and found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1410) which answered it for me.

What you can do is call the `describe()` method on your schemas before saving them to a file. This will [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json) them into a simpler form. Then, when reading the serialized version from your file, use `Joi.build()` and pass in your serialized schema to deserialize them back into `Joi` objects. Just make sure to parse stringified JSON back into an object first.