# Mapping over an array of objects that is inside a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

[image][image]I want to map over this array of objects below in react Js, how do I go about it?

```
'[{"items":[{"name":"meat","price":"4"},{"name":"metty","price":"2"}],"name":"Merry food","price":null},{"items":[{"name":"beaf","price":"3"},{"name":"fish","price":"4"}],"name":"Means","price":null}]'
```

Comment: It's `arrayName.map(item => logic)`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking or whether you've made any attempt at solving this yourself. If you have add that code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @MattPengelly i think i should reprhase the question, what I am getting from the backend is "[{"items":[{"name":"meat","price":"4"},{"name":"metty","price":"2"}],"name":"Merry food","price":null},{"items":[{"name":"beaf","price":"3"},{"name":"fish","price":"4"}],"name":"Means","price":null}]" iterating over this is a problem, i have tried Array.from and yet i am getting null

Comment: @MattPengelly it has "[]" if you notice, i cant get out of that now?

Comment: @MattPengelly i added an image of what I am trying to achieve to my question now

Comment: yes i noticed now. thanks. looking

Comment: please also show a desired *output format*, you simply want to map over an array of arrays or objects, but mapping implies an output format. should it be a single array of objects? or a single array of names/props? without more details we cannot know.

Comment: @MattPengelly the mapping is not the issue now but the format in which the array is coming from the backend, I posted a picture of what I am getting from the backend now, notice the "[]", its just trying to convert that to an array now so it can be iterable that's the issue now, tried Array.from and yet, getting error

Comment: @MattPengelly i had to parse the data coming from the backend, but I don't think that should be good enough for that. Thanks

Comment: without an output format, this is impossible to answer. @konradLinkowski has 1 way to map over the contents, but you will lose data that way. Since you did not specify a desired *output format* its not possible to answer the question any better then he did already.

Comment: You're getting a **string**, not an array. The string contains a **serialised** (stringified) array, so you need to **deserialise** it. It looks like [serialised JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json) so you should be able to deserialise it into an array using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like `JSON.parse(data.add_ons).map((item) => doSomething(item))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use a map function that is provied for arrays in Javascript.

```
data.map((item) => console.log(item));
```

You can view the example I created for your data here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zp4b2r?file=App.tsx

Comment: can i send a screenshot of what i am trying to achieve, this is what I am getting from the backend "[{"items":[{"name":"meat","price":"4"},{"name":"metty","price":"2"}],"name":"Merry food","price":null},{"items":[{"name":"beaf","price":"3"},{"name":"fish","price":"4"}],"name":"Means","price":null}]" and i can iterate over that, what i'll attach a screenshot of what i am trying to achieve to my post

Comment: yes , please attach the screenshot of what you are getting

Comment: I added a screenshot of what i am trying to do by editing my post

Comment: @Ayodele i have attached a link in the above comment that maps the array you gave and also the array inside that array to. please watch that example if that solves your problem

Comment: yes i have seen it, but the array is not iteratable on my end, what I have now if you notice on the correction I posted, this is what I am getting from the backend"[]" notice the array is wrapped in a string like expression, how do I do that?

Comment: @Ayodele if you visit the link then I have assigned the array you are getting to a variable called data and mapped it. It cannot be that hard.Please visit the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zp4b2r?file=App.tsx if you have time.

Comment: i tried array.from and i still got an error, let me post  you the exact data I am getting from the backend "[{"items":[{"name":"meat","price":"4"},{"name":"metty","price":"2"}],"name":"Merry food","price":null},{"items":[{"name":"beaf","price":"3"},{"name":"fish","price":"4"}],"name":"Means","price":null}]"

Comment: @Ayodele can you show the screen shots of error you are getting?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the data I am getting from the backend" in my questions now, kindly check it out

Comment: i had to parse the data coming from the backend, but I don't think that should be good enough for that. Thanks

Comment: I will still love to see your solution though

Comment: @Ayodele if you see carefully in my solution , that is the way and you can map the inner array as well

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [{"items":[{"name":"meat","price":"4"},{"name":"metty","price":"2"}],"name":"Merry food","price":null},{"items":[{"name":"beaf","price":"3"},{"name":"fish","price":"4"}],"name":"Means","price":null}]
const List = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(datum => datum.items.map(item => 
        <div>item.name</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: this discards the non-children properties such as "Means", im unsure if OP actually wants that or not based on their question

Comment: Everyone's missing that `add_ons` in the example is a **string**, not an array... it needs to be deserialised first, like `JSON.parse(data).map( ...`