# Test receives different ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring

I have a weird issue with a unit test and `ResponseEntity`. Here's the test:

```
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void createEntityTest() {
    EntityRequestDTO requestDTO = new EntityRequestDTO();
    dto.setTitle("foo");
    dto.setDescription("bar");
    ResponseEntity<EntityResponseDTO> postResponse = 
        testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/api/test", dto, EntityResponseDTO.class);
    EntityResponseDTO responseDTO = postResponse.getBody();
    
    assertThat(responseDTO.getTitle()).isEqualTo("foo");
    assertThat(responseDTO.getDescription()).isEqualTo("bar");
    assertThat(responseDTO.getFullname()).isEqualTo("foobar");
}
```

The full name is set in the background by service. The issue is, this last assertion fails. `getFullname()` returns `null`. That may be because of several reasons, but, here's the controller endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/api/test")
public ResponseEntity<EntityResponseDTO> create(@RequestBody EntityRequestDTO requestDTO) {
    Entity saved = entityService.add(requestDTO);
    EntityResponseDTO savedDto = new EntityResponseDTO(saved);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(saved.getId())
                .toUri();
    ResponseEntity<EntityResponseDTO> resEntity = ResponseEntity.created(location).body(savedDto);
    System.out.println("Before: ResponseEntity in controller.");
    System.out.println(resEntity.getBody().getFullname());
}
```

However here, just before returning the `ResponseEntity` the `System.out.println(resEntity.getBody().getFullname())` method prints `foobar`. I can't wrap my head around this. What is going on?

**Note**: I have `@JsonIgnore` on the `fullname` field because I want it to be present, but not shown in the response. When removing annotation, test passes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `@JsonIgnore` is the issue here. As the name suggests, `@JsonIgnore` annotation ignores the corresponding field in serialisation. That means it will not be included in your response. This does not affect what you are doing in your `create` method. Therefore it gets printed successfully.

Removing `@JsonIgnore` will resolve this. To read more on `@JsonIgnore` - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonignore.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. When receiving the `ResponseEntity` in the field, can I still receive JSON body without the field `fullname`, but still be able to read the value under it in tests (I've tried the `value` option of `@JsonIgnore`)?

Comment: And, if I understand correctly, the serialization happens when passing the object into `ResponseEntity`. How come, then, that the `ResponseEntity` in controller persists the `fullname` value?

Comment: Serialisation happens when you convert an object (`EntityResponseDTO` in this case) to a string (to a `JSON` in this case). What happens in your REST endpoint is that you serialise the `EntityResponseDTO` when sending it over as the response. That's why `fullname` is not available in the response. You can find it in the controller since you take it from the object in the controller side.

Comment: More on serialisation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json

Comment: OK. I read it, but I still have no clue how to achieve what I want. I've stumbled upon `@JsonIgnore` on the getter, but `@JsonPropety` on the setter. I've stumbled upon `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`. I've stumbled upon class annotation. None of the solutions worked for me. I really am helpless. :/

Comment: Could you explain more on what you are trying to achieve? If you don't want the `fullname` to be present in the response, then you can use `@JsonIgnore`. If you want to it to be present, then you should not use the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

Comment: I'd like the above test to pass. I'd like the fullname to not be present in the JSON response, but I'd still like to be able to get `fullname` by `getFullname()` method, which - currently - returns null.

Comment: Note: the fullname *is* present in controller. Not the test

Comment: If you don't want `fullname` to be present in the JSON response, then you have done correctly. That means on the receiving side there isn't a value received for `fullname`. Hence the `getFullname()` method gives a null. There isn't a way to get the value of fullname from the receiving end (Test method in your case) because the value never came with the response. Hope you understand this.

Comment: Hm, okay. I was convinced there was a way to do so. Then, I have no clue what the `access` is for in `@JsonIgnore`.