# How to parse Json in C# which has multiple nested models

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core

I am trying to figure out logic to write a method to parse the data which will be in Json format.

```js
    {
    "meals": [
    {
    "id": 279205,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "image": "https://d15rxdoyo1waj2.cloudfront.net/production/image?b=snaq-app-production&i=meals/279204/image.jpg&w=1200&q=90",
    "mealName": "Smoked salmon ala Mamma",
    "mealTime": "2023-09-08T14:17:52Z",
    "ingredients": [
    {
    "name": "Carrot"
    },
    {
    "name": "Lemon"
    },
    {
    "name": "Arugula"
    },
    {
    "name": "Salmon Grilled"
    }
    ],
    "nutrition": {
    "carbohydrates": {
    "unit": "g",
    "value": 8
    },
    "fatTotal": {
    "unit": "g",
    "value": 22
    },
    "protein": {
    "unit": "g",
    "value": 34
    },
    "dietryFibers": {
    "unit": "g",
    "value": 4
    },
    "energy": {
    "unit": "kcal",
    "value": 365
    }
    },
    "weight": {
    "unit": "g",
    "value": 302
    }
    }
    ],
    "insulinDelivery": [
    {
    "id": 123456,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "injectionTime": "2023-09-09T13:12:12Z",
    "insulinType": "SHORT",
    "unit": "units",
    "value": 5.0
    }
    ],
    "workouts": [
    {
    "id": 10223,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "startDate": "2023-09-10T10:52:23Z",
    "endDate": "2023-09-10T11:35:45Z",
    "intensity": "EASY",
    Datastructure 2
    "workoutName": "Baseball"
    }
    ],
    "steps": [
    {
    "startDate": "2023-09-18T14:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2023-09-18T15:00:00Z",
    "stepCount": "1500"
    }
    ]
    }
```

I am thinking how to write method to parse this Json payload in C#

Comment: Very unclear what problem you have with parsing of JSON - please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and data and make sure code (and JSON sample) provided in the question *demonstrate* the problem (rather than dumping bunch of code of you current project). Also review tags you've added to the post - it is not clear how "core" is related to this question (as it talks about CPUs and threading - neither is shown in the Q). After reviewing the info [edit] the question (instead of posting bunch of *comments*.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I need to write an api in which we will be receiving data in form of json . I need to figure out we need to deserialize this json ? and parse it ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Newtonsoft's JSON library. It can let you [deserialize into objects directly](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm). Below is the sample from their website:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

If you want to avoid deserializing directly into your classes (for instance, if you are going to have private variables), you can do something like:

```
Dictionary<string, object> jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: are we doing to deserialize first and then parse it ? or after deserializing we will not need parsing?

Answer (score 0):

'myJsonResponse is your json string  (check your json, the line  `DataStructure 2` doesn't seem to fit there)

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

public class Carbohydrates
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class DietryFibers
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Energy
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class FatTotal
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class InsulinDelivery
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime injectionTime { get; set; }
    public string insulinType { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class Meal
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string mealName { get; set; }
    public DateTime mealTime { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }
    public Nutrition nutrition { get; set; }
    public Weight weight { get; set; }
}

public class Nutrition
{
    public Carbohydrates carbohydrates { get; set; }
    public FatTotal fatTotal { get; set; }
    public Protein protein { get; set; }
    public DietryFibers dietryFibers { get; set; }
    public Energy energy { get; set; }
}

public class Protein
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Meal> meals { get; set; }
    public List<InsulinDelivery> insulinDelivery { get; set; }
    public List<Workout> workouts { get; set; }
    public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public string stepCount { get; set; }
}

public class Weight
{
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Workout
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public string intensity { get; set; }
    public string workoutName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Serialize? Deserialize?

---

Please refer to: [What is deserialize and serialize in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316762/what-is-deserialize-and-serialize-in-json)

TL;DR: Serialize=object to json, Deserialize=json to object.

### 2. Do we need to deserialize json into objects?

---

If you're using ASP.NET / ASP.NET Core, the application will handle it for you, but you need to define your controller, and tell the application what input do you expect, in the sense of class, so it automatically deserialize into that type.

[Allen King already provided necessary classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406262/16606026) it seems, so you can build a controller base on that:

```cs
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SomeEndpoint(Root root)
    {
       // If input format is as expected, ASP.NET will deserialize the json into the root in this function's parameter.
       DoSomething(root); // you then use the root.
    }
}
```

[MSDN on how to make controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)