# How to save feature importance plot of xgboost to a file from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I am struggling with saving the xgboost feature-importance plot to a file. I have created a model and plotted importance of features in my jupyter notebook-

```
xgb_model = xgboost.train(best_params, dtrain, num_round)
xgboost.plot_importance(xgb_model)
```

It shows me the feature importance plot but I am unable to save it to a file. I even looked for any **save** attribute in `dir(xgboost.plot_importance(xgb_model))`, but got nothing. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According the [doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.82/python/python_api.html?highlight=plot#xgboost.plot_importance), `xgboost.plot_importance(xgb_model)` returns `matplotlib Axes`

therefore, you can just

```
ax = xgboost.plot_importance(xgb_model)
ax.figure.savefig('the-path-you-want-to-save.png')
```

---

Additional, if your loss the left and right margins for your figure, you can set the [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.tight_layout)

```
ax = xgboost.plot_importance(xgb_model)
ax.figure.tight_layout()
ax.figure.savefig('the-path-you-want-to-save.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=plot#xgboost.plot_importance) you see it is a `matplotlib` output. So you should be able to call `savefig` of matplotlib.

If you want to save the model, take a look at [How to save & load xgboost model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691380/how-to-save-load-xgboost-model).