# Opening a pickled sklearn file in R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does anyone know if I am able to open a pickled sklearn Python algorithm in R? Or if I can save a trained model in sklearn in a different way that can be opened and used in R? Specifically, I am looking at a gradient boosting model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing what you are doing. It's a lot of extra work that you don't need.

However, in case you find yourself obliged to do that, I would think of saving my model in the binary format. This your best option.

This is possible for Xgboost see link [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/xgboost/man/xgb.save.html#heading-1).

Read this answer on how to save xgboost as a binary file: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691380/how-to-save-load-xgboost-model)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Reticulate package, it will allow you to call python code from R.

https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/