# Can't save/load model using keras.load_model - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save

I am using tf and Keras to create a cycleGAN following the approach used [here](https://hardikbansal.github.io/CycleGANBlog/) and [here](https://github.com/Shaofanl/CycleGAN-keras/blob/master/CycleGAN/models/cyclegan.py)

The network structure is quite complex: there are many models nested in each other.

I am not able to save and reload the trained model.

After the training is complete i used

```
 generator_AtoB.save("models/generator_AtoB.h5")
```

and

```
pickle.dump(generator_AtoB, saveFile)
```

to save the model: this causes no errors and a file is created in the path provided.

By checking with `h5dump | less` I can see that the .h5 file contains data.

Reloading the model later by using keras:

```
generator_AtoB = load_model("models/generator_AtoB.h5")
```

or pickle:

```
pickle.load(saveFile)
```

Causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_model.py", line 14, in <module>
generator_AtoB = pickle.load(saveFile)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1266, in __setstate__
model = saving.unpickle_model(state)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 435, in unpickle_model
return _deserialize_model(f)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 274, in _deserialize_model
reshape=False)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 682, in preprocess_weights_for_loading
weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 658, in convert_nested_model
original_backend=original_backend))
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 682, in preprocess_weights_for_loading
weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 670, in convert_nested_model
original_backend=original_backend))
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 682, in preprocess_weights_for_loading
weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 658, in convert_nested_model
original_backend=original_backend))
File "/home/MYUSERNAME/.virtualenvs/tensorflow_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 800, in preprocess_weights_for_loading
elif layer_weights_shape != weights[0].shape:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error is the same if using `keras.load_model` or `pickle.load`

Since this happens both by saving with keras or pickle, I am thinking this is not a save/load problem, but something I am saving wrongly inside the model, but I cannot find any reference anywhere.

Thank you for your help

Full code ahead:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# https://hardikbansal.github.io/CycleGANBlog/
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, multiply, add as kadd
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, ReLU
from keras.layers import Activation

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from PIL import Image



ngf = 32 # Number of filters in first layer of generator
ndf = 64 # Number of filters in first layer of discriminator
BATCH_SIZE = 1 # batch_size
pool_size = 50 # pool_size
IMG_WIDTH = 256 # Imput image will of width 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256 # Input image will be of height 256
IMG_DEPTH = 3 # RGB format

DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS = 1
SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL = 25

ITERATIONS = 5000
FAKE_POOL_SIZE=25
INPUT_SHAPE = (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH)


def resnet_block(num_features):

    block = Sequential()
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())


    resblock_input = Input(shape=(64, 64, 256))
    conv_model = block(resblock_input)

    _sum = kadd([resblock_input, conv_model])

    composed =  Model(inputs=[resblock_input], outputs=_sum)
    return composed


def discriminator( f=4, name=None):
    d = Sequential()
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_1"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 2, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_2"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 4, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_3"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 8, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_4"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=f, strides=1, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_out"))

    # d.add(Activation("sigmoid"))


    model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

    decision  = d(model_input)

    composed = Model(model_input, decision)
    # print(d.output_shape)
    # d.summary()

    return composed

def generator(name=None):

    g = Sequential()
    # ENCODER
    g.add(Conv2D(ngf, kernel_size=7,
            strides=1,
            # activation='relu',
            padding='SAME',
            input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,
            name="encoder_0" ))


    g.add(Conv2D(64*2, kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            padding='SAME',
            name="encoder_1" ))
    # output shape = (128, 128, 128)


    g.add(Conv2D(64*4, kernel_size=3,
            padding="SAME",
            strides=2,))
    # output shape = (64, 64, 256)

    # END ENCODER


    # TRANSFORM

    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))

    # END TRANSFORM
    # generator.shape = (64, 64, 256)

    # DECODER

    g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))
    g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))

    g.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=7, strides=1, padding="SAME"))

    # END DECODER

    model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
    generated_image = g(model_input)

    composed = Model(model_input, generated_image, name=name)
    return composed


def fromMinusOneToOne(x):
    return x/127.5 -1

def toRGB(x):
    return (1+x) * 127.5


def createImageGenerator( subset="train", data_type="A", batch_size=1, pp=None):

    # we create two instances with the same arguments
    data_gen_args = dict(
                         preprocessing_function= pp,
                         zoom_range=0.1)

    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
    seed = 1

    image_directory=subset+data_type
    print('data/vangogh2photo/'+image_directory)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/vangogh2photo/'+image_directory,
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        seed=seed)

    return image_generator


if __name__ == '__main__':

    generator_AtoB = generator(name="gen_A")
    generator_BtoA = generator(name="gen_B")

    discriminator_A = discriminator(name="disc_A")
    discriminator_B = discriminator(name="disc_B")


    # input_A = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_A")
    input_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_A")
    generated_B = generator_AtoB(input_A)
    discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)
    cyc_A = generator_BtoA(generated_B)


    input_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_B")
    generated_A = generator_BtoA(input_B)
    discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A )
    cyc_B = generator_AtoB(generated_A)


    ### GENERATOR TRAINING
    optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)


    # cyclic error is increased, because it's more important
    cyclic_weight_multipier = 10

    generator_trainer =  Model([input_A, input_B],
                 [discriminator_generated_B,   discriminator_generated_A,
                 cyc_A,      cyc_B,])

    losses =         [ "MSE", "MSE", "MAE",                   "MAE"]
    losses_weights = [ 1,     1,     cyclic_weight_multipier, cyclic_weight_multipier]

    generator_trainer.compile(optimizer=optim, loss = losses, loss_weights=losses_weights)



    ### DISCRIMINATOR TRAINING

    disc_optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

    real_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_A")
    real_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_B")

    generated_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_A")
    generated_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_B")

    discriminator_real_A = discriminator_A(real_A)
    discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A)
    discriminator_real_B =  discriminator_B(real_B)
    discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)

    disc_trainer = Model([real_A, generated_A, real_B, generated_B],
                         [  discriminator_real_A,
                            discriminator_generated_A,
                            discriminator_real_B,
                            discriminator_generated_B] )


    disc_trainer.compile(optimizer=disc_optim, loss = 'MSE')


    #########
    ##
    ## TRAINING
    ##
    #########


    fake_A_pool = []
    fake_B_pool = []


    ones = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])
    zeros = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])


    train_A_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "A")
    train_B_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "B")


    it = 1
    while it  < ITERATIONS:
        start = time.time()
        print("\nIteration %d " % it)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # THIS ONLY WORKS IF BATCH SIZE == 1
        real_A = train_A_image_generator.next()

        real_B = train_B_image_generator.next()

        fake_A_pool.extend(generator_BtoA.predict(real_B))
        fake_B_pool.extend(generator_AtoB.predict(real_A))

        #resize pool
        fake_A_pool = fake_A_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]
        fake_B_pool = fake_B_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]

        fake_A = [ fake_A_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_A_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]
        fake_B = [ fake_B_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_B_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]

        fake_A = np.array(fake_A)
        fake_B = np.array(fake_B)


        for x in range(0, DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS):
            _, D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B = \
            disc_trainer.train_on_batch(
                [real_A, fake_A, real_B, fake_B],
                [zeros, ones * 0.9, zeros, ones * 0.9] )


        print("=====")
        print("Discriminator loss:")
        print("Real A: %s, Fake A: %s || Real B: %s, Fake B: %s " % ( D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B))

        _, G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_rec_B = \
            generator_trainer.train_on_batch(
                [real_A, real_B],
                [zeros, zeros, real_A, real_B])


        print("=====")
        print("Generator loss:")
        print("Fake B: %s, Cyclic A: %s || Fake A: %s, Cyclic B: %s " % (G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_B))

        end = time.time()
        print("Iteration time: %s s" % (end-start))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if not (it % SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL ):
            imgA = real_A
            # print(imgA.shape)
            imga2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgA)
            # print(imga2b.shape)
            imga2b2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imga2b)
            # print(imga2b2a.shape)
            imgB = real_B
            imgb2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imgB)
            imgb2a2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgb2a)

            c = np.concatenate([imgA, imga2b, imga2b2a, imgB, imgb2a, imgb2a2b], axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
            # print(c.shape)
            x = Image.fromarray(c[0])
            x.save("data/generated/iteration_%s.jpg" % str(it).zfill(4))

        it+=1


        generator_AtoB.save("models/generator_AtoB.h5")
        generator_BtoA.save("models/generator_BtoA.h5")
```

Comment: please complete code, you are using.

Comment: Try this with `tf.keras` API.

Comment: thank you, i added full code; i'm not familiar with tf.keras api, what are you referring to ?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue.  Ankish's suggestion to try this with the tf.keras API solved it.  I don't know why, but...

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("./saved_models/our_model.h5", compile=False)
```

works perfectly, while

```
keras.models.load_model("./saved_models/our_model.h5")
```

fails with the listed error here.  The compile flag being set to false is just to hide a warning.

Comment: Still get the same error with `compile=False`

Answer (score 1):

I would generalise Ankish and Josh's answers, and import everything from tensorflow keras API. First install Tensorflow 2 (`pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` if using pip, detailed instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)). Then, import tensorflow and replace your import statements by switching to`tensorflow.keras` on each of the `keras` imports:

```py
# ...
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

import tf.keras as keras
from tf.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tf.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, multiply, add as kadd
from tf.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
from tf.keras.layers import LeakyReLU, ReLU
from tf.keras.layers import Activation

from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#...
```

With these changes, the rest of the code can remain unchanged.

Comment: Problem still persists for me. Also I only have `tf.python.keras. ...`

Comment: @CGFoX What version of tensorflow did you install?

Comment: My version is tensorflow 2.8

Answer (score 1):

tf.keras is the Tensorflow specific implementation of the Keras API specification. but keras is an API specification that describes how a Deep Learning framework.

tf.keras adds the framework the support for Tensorflow specific features.

change your code :
import keras  to import tensorflow.keras

Answer (score 0):

Do not use pickle, use joblib instead. See the comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615525/what-are-the-different-use-cases-of-joblib-versus-pickle). Joblib has a similar interface to pickle, ie.:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(model, '<path>')  # Save
model = joblib.load('<path>') # Load
```

Personally I prefer this method, because I can use it for SciKit-Learn and Keras models. Note however that it does not work if you use Keras through TensorFlow (`import tf.keras as keras`), because in such case you have to rely on native serializers and initialize the graph engine when you are loading models from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are building a website. PHP is your programming language and SQL SERVER is your **backend**. Now you can also use PostgreSQL or MYSQL as your database, however, your PHP code used to interact with the database will not change.

You can think of the backend as your database and Keras as your programming language used to access the database. Originally, Keras' default backend was Theano. With the release of Keras v1.1.0, Tensorflow is the default backend. **Google announced** TensorFlow 2.0 in June 2019, they declared that Keras is now the official high-level API of TensorFlow for quick and easy model design and training.

That's why you have to use **tf.keras** or **tensorflow.keras**

```
import sys
import time

import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, multiply, add as kadd
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU, ReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from PIL import Image



ngf = 32 # Number of filters in first layer of generator
ndf = 64 # Number of filters in first layer of discriminator
BATCH_SIZE = 1 # batch_size
pool_size = 50 # pool_size
IMG_WIDTH = 256 # Imput image will of width 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256 # Input image will be of height 256
IMG_DEPTH = 3 # RGB format

DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS = 1
SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL = 25

ITERATIONS = 5000
FAKE_POOL_SIZE=25
INPUT_SHAPE = (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH)


def resnet_block(num_features):

    block = Sequential()
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())


    resblock_input = Input(shape=(64, 64, 256))
    conv_model = block(resblock_input)

    _sum = kadd([resblock_input, conv_model])

    composed =  Model(inputs=[resblock_input], outputs=_sum)
    return composed


def discriminator( f=4, name=None):
    d = Sequential()
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME",         name="discr_conv2d_1"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 2, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_2"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 4, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_3"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 8, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_4"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=f, strides=1, padding="SAME", name="discr_conv2d_out"))

# d.add(Activation("sigmoid"))


model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

decision  = d(model_input)

composed = Model(model_input, decision)
# print(d.output_shape)
# d.summary()

return composed

def generator(name=None):

    g = Sequential()
    # ENCODER
    g.add(Conv2D(ngf, kernel_size=7,
        strides=1,
        # activation='relu',
        padding='SAME',
        input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,
        name="encoder_0" ))


g.add(Conv2D(64*2, kernel_size=3,
        strides=2,
        padding='SAME',
        name="encoder_1" ))
# output shape = (128, 128, 128)


g.add(Conv2D(64*4, kernel_size=3,
        padding="SAME",
        strides=2,))
# output shape = (64, 64, 256)

# END ENCODER


# TRANSFORM

g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
g.add(resnet_block(64*4))

# END TRANSFORM
# generator.shape = (64, 64, 256)

# DECODER

g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))
g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))

g.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=7, strides=1, padding="SAME"))

# END DECODER

model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
generated_image = g(model_input)

composed = Model(model_input, generated_image, name=name)
return composed


def fromMinusOneToOne(x):
    return x/127.5 -1

def toRGB(x):
    return (1+x) * 127.5


def createImageGenerator( subset="train", data_type="A", batch_size=1, pp=None):

    # we create two instances with the same arguments
    data_gen_args = dict(
                         preprocessing_function= pp,
                         zoom_range=0.1)

    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
    seed = 1

    image_directory=subset+data_type
    print('data/vangogh2photo/'+image_directory)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/vangogh2photo/'+image_directory,
    class_mode=None,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=seed)

return image_generator


if __name__ == '__main__':

generator_AtoB = generator(name="gen_A")
generator_BtoA = generator(name="gen_B")

discriminator_A = discriminator(name="disc_A")
discriminator_B = discriminator(name="disc_B")


# input_A = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_A")
input_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_A")
generated_B = generator_AtoB(input_A)
discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)
cyc_A = generator_BtoA(generated_B)


input_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_B")
generated_A = generator_BtoA(input_B)
discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A )
cyc_B = generator_AtoB(generated_A)


### GENERATOR TRAINING
optim = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)


# cyclic error is increased, because it's more important
cyclic_weight_multipier = 10

generator_trainer =  Model([input_A, input_B],
             [discriminator_generated_B,   discriminator_generated_A,
             cyc_A,      cyc_B,])

losses =         [ "MSE", "MSE", "MAE",                   "MAE"]
losses_weights = [ 1,     1,     cyclic_weight_multipier, cyclic_weight_multipier]

generator_trainer.compile(optimizer=optim, loss = losses, loss_weights=losses_weights)



### DISCRIMINATOR TRAINING

disc_optim = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

real_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_A")
real_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_B")

generated_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_A")
generated_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_B")

discriminator_real_A = discriminator_A(real_A)
discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A)
discriminator_real_B =  discriminator_B(real_B)
discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)

disc_trainer = Model([real_A, generated_A, real_B, generated_B],
                     [  discriminator_real_A,
                        discriminator_generated_A,
                        discriminator_real_B,
                        discriminator_generated_B] )


disc_trainer.compile(optimizer=disc_optim, loss = 'MSE')


#########
##
## TRAINING
##
#########


fake_A_pool = []
fake_B_pool = []


ones = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])
zeros = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])


train_A_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "A")
train_B_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "B")


it = 1
while it  < ITERATIONS:
    start = time.time()
    print("\nIteration %d " % it)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    # THIS ONLY WORKS IF BATCH SIZE == 1
    real_A = train_A_image_generator.next()

    real_B = train_B_image_generator.next()

    fake_A_pool.extend(generator_BtoA.predict(real_B))
    fake_B_pool.extend(generator_AtoB.predict(real_A))

    #resize pool
    fake_A_pool = fake_A_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]
    fake_B_pool = fake_B_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]

    fake_A = [ fake_A_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_A_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]
    fake_B = [ fake_B_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_B_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]

    fake_A = np.array(fake_A)
    fake_B = np.array(fake_B)


    for x in range(0, DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS):
        _, D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B = \
        disc_trainer.train_on_batch(
            [real_A, fake_A, real_B, fake_B],
            [zeros, ones * 0.9, zeros, ones * 0.9] )


    print("=====")
    print("Discriminator loss:")
    print("Real A: %s, Fake A: %s || Real B: %s, Fake B: %s " % ( D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B))

    _, G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_rec_B = \
        generator_trainer.train_on_batch(
            [real_A, real_B],
            [zeros, zeros, real_A, real_B])


    print("=====")
    print("Generator loss:")
    print("Fake B: %s, Cyclic A: %s || Fake A: %s, Cyclic B: %s " % (G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_B))

    end = time.time()
    print("Iteration time: %s s" % (end-start))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    if not (it % SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL ):
        imgA = real_A
        # print(imgA.shape)
        imga2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgA)
        # print(imga2b.shape)
        imga2b2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imga2b)
        # print(imga2b2a.shape)
        imgB = real_B
        imgb2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imgB)
        imgb2a2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgb2a)

        c = np.concatenate([imgA, imga2b, imga2b2a, imgB, imgb2a, imgb2a2b], axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
        # print(c.shape)
        x = Image.fromarray(c[0])
        x.save("data/generated/iteration_%s.jpg" % str(it).zfill(4))

    it+=1


    generator_AtoB.save("models/generator_AtoB.h5")
    generator_BtoA.save("models/generator_BtoA.h5")
```