# What is the fastest way to save and load a large data in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, joblib

I'm currently using pickle to save some big data which contains many numpy matrices of size 10k*10k. Even though I use several similar (separate) python files, whenever I save the data, the size of the saved dat file is always 4 GB. So, is that just a coincidence or it can't save more than this amount?

Also, when I load the data it uses more than 90% of the memory, which is not useful to me. I have heard of cpickle and joblib, here a comparison of them: [What are the different use cases of joblib versus pickle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615525/what-are-the-different-use-cases-of-joblib-versus-pickle)

I would like to reduce memory usage. Should I switch to the joblib? What would be the fastest way?

Thanks for any suggestions.

p.s. I use Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Spyder IDE.

Comment: Can you give more detailed  informations on this data, or better a example?

Comment: It consists of some arrays, maybe 6-7 of them, which have dimensions 10000*10000. What else do you need?

Comment: Pickle and Joblib are comfortable, but slow and produce quite large files. If your data is for example only a list of some arrays adapting an answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761075/4045774 can be a good solution.