# to_csv takes too much time to complete for xml object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an xml object which needs to be written to a file. I see that this takes more than 1 hour to complete for 10,000 records. I tried to convert using `df_merge['xml'] = df_merge['xml'].astype(str)`. Still time taken is similar i.e. more than 1 hour just that `astype(str)` takes more time. So, whatever be the scenario, it takes more than 1 hour to complete `to_csv`.
So, can I please know how to write large xml object to a file quickly?
Size of 10000 xmls will be around 600 MB.

```
df_merge.to_csv(settings.OUTPUT_XML, encoding='utf-8', index=False,
                columns=['xml'])
```

Later I tried to use `np.savetxt` which also takes similar time.

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('output_xml.txt', df_merge['xml'], encoding='utf-8', fmt="%s")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`serialization`](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/). A good library for that is [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why.html), or other common serialization tools like [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPickling%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20process%20whereby,back%20into%20an%20object%20hierarchy.)

[A good Stack Overflow post outlining the differences and when to use each is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615525/what-are-the-different-use-cases-of-joblib-versus-pickle)

In your case, you might be able to serialize your object and it would be done so in much more time, using some example code from below:

```
# Import joblib's dump function
from joblib import dump

# For speed, keep compression = 0
dump(df_merge, 'df_merge.joblib')

# For smaller file size, you can increase compression, though it will slow your write time
# dump(df_merge, 'df_merge.joblib', compress=9)
```

You can then use `joblib` to load the file, like so:

```
# Import joblib's load function
from joblib import load

# For speed, keep compression = 0
# Note, if you used compress=n, then it will take longer to load
df_merge = load('df_merge.joblib')
```