# Pickling in python 2

Tags: python, pickle

i want to ask why we should pickle an object in python ?
why the file that we want to pickle should be opened in binary mode ?
and what is the HIGHEST_PROTOCOL used in pickling ?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) might be a good place to start

Comment: You can look at [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) as well.

Comment: didn't understood it too much :/

Comment: As far as why pickle, this might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438675/common-use-cases-for-pickle-in-python?rq=1

Comment: kind of a duplicate… see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968884/python-serialization-why-pickle/19360828#19360828

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't "have to" pickle an object, but in case you want to (for purpose of saving it, sending it etc) you can use pickling (serializing).
2. from the *[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)*:

> **Note:** Be sure to always open pickle files created with protocols >= 1
>   in binary mode. ...

it means that only files that weren't created using ASCII protocol (protocol 0) should be opened in binary mode. As for why - the answer is probably in the implementation of pickling.

- `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` is another way of naming the "latest" protocol