# How to convert a file into a list and then that list into a dictionary and load it into the program everytime I run it

Tags: python

I made a User login system in which user must enter one of three alphabets that is x to stop the program, y if you are a new user and n if you are not a new user.

```
self.register = input('Enter y if you have register or n if you are new or x to quit:')
```

If user enter's 'n' then it will create a new user and store it into a dictionary:-
ex:- username = Fread
     password = hello

{'Fread':'hello'}

From here if user enter's y then it will check if te user exist with this condition:-

```
        self.existing_Id = input('Please enter your existing id here:')
        self.existing_Password = input('Please enter your existing password here:')
        if self.existing_Id in self.save and self.save[self.id] == self.password:
            print('you have successfully logged in')
        else:
            print('user not found please try again')
```

Also if the user already exist then it will also not create a user:-

```
        while True:
        self.id = input('please enter your ID here:')
        if self.id in self.save:
            print('User already exist!!!')
            break
```

Here i am trying to save all the username and password into file then everytime i stop and rerun te code again it should load all the previous saved file into a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization) : Turning python objects into things you can write into files, and back into python objects.

Python has some built in capabilities in the form of [pickles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) :

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle

SAVE_FILE = Path('some/path/file.pickle')

def save_state(state_dict):
    pickle.dump(state_dict, SAVE_FILE)

def restore_state():
    return pickle.load(SAVE_FILE)
```

In this example, you can use the `save_state` function before exiting the program to write your data to `some/path/file.saved`, and `load_state` when you open to read data.

Note that pickling has some security issues if the saved state file will be handled by someone malicious. In those circumstances, you could do a similar job with the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module,  albeit with a little less leway with the data structures you could store in the file.

```py
import JSON
from pathlib import Path

SAVE_FILE = Path('some/path/file.json')

def save_state(state_dict):
    JSON.dump(state_dict, SAVE_FILE)

def restore_state():
    return JSON.load(SAVE_FILE)
```