# Unable to reference 2D array of game objects in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm creating chess in unity, and I want to create the chess board using a 2D array of cells. I was able to create an array of pieces and could reference them with their respective prefabs in Unity. But I have no option to reference the 2D array.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[,] cell = new GameObject[7,7];
    public GameObject[] Wpawn = new GameObject[7];
    public GameObject[] Bpawn  = new GameObject[7];
    public GameObject[] Wrook = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject[] Brook = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject[] Wknight = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject[] Bknight = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject[] Wbishop = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject[] Bbishop = new GameObject[1];
    public GameObject Wking;
    public GameObject Bking;
    public GameObject Wqueen;
    public GameObject Bqueen;

    bool[] Bpawn2 = new bool[7];
    bool[] Wpawn2 = new bool[7];

    short turn = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        #region Board
        for (float y = 0F; y <= 7; y+= 1)
        {
            for (float x = 0F; x <= 7F; x+= 1)
            {
                if (y % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (x % 2 == 0)
                    {
                       cell[(int)x,(int)y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray; 
                    } else if (x % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        cell[(int)x,(int)y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white; 
                    }
                
                } else if (y % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if (x % 2 == 0)
                    {
                       cell[(int)x,(int)y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white; 
                    } else if (x % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        cell[(int)x,(int)y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray; 
                    }
                }
                Instantiate(cell[(int)x,(int)y], new Vector3(x - 3.5F, y -3.5F), transform.rotation);
                
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

As you can see I've properly initialized my 2D array. I only showed you the setboard Region because there were no problems in the rest.

Here is the gamemanager script component and what it is showing me.

[image]

There is no option to reference the Cell Prefab

Comment: Downvoted for not showing proper research effort. Answered as it's a valid question and comes up often.

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh I couldn't research it because I didn't know what keywords to use. Everytime I search it up it shows me something that isn't my problem. I didn't know about serializing. Thanks for explaining though.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

The default Inspector can only show variables that are Serializable by Unity's Serializer, i.e. files which can be written-to and read-from a file by Unity for saving/loading purposes. 2D arrays are not Serializable, thus they're not visible in the Inspector.

Please familiarize yourself with the [Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) rules in Unity. Here's an answer about [what Serialization is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633402/what-is-serialization)

## Alternative

Even List<List> or T[][] type 2D arrays are not Serializable. This has to do with limitations regarding generic serialization in Unity. A simple alternative to define a concrete class as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class GameObjectList //not a monobehavior
{
    public List<GameObject> gameObjects;
}
```

using it later on as field

```
public GameObjectList[] pieces;
```

This should show up a list of lists in the Inspector, letting you reference your GameObjects. Of course, this method is a bit cumbersome, having to define a new class every time, but it works.

### Notes:

A lot of the limitations surrounding generic serialization have been lifted in Unity 2020.2 update, but you still can't serialize 2D arrays/lists directly.

Comment: Serializable yes but as correctly said Unity does not serilaize it ;)

Comment: Will your alternative allow me to Reference my Game Objects?

Comment: Yes, it will allow you to reference your game objects. @ALK003